# Quiero saber como pasar un arreglo de struct por referencia en c

Tags: c, struct

El problema es el siguiente quiero pasar un arreglo, array de struct por referencia para poder rellenar mis struct por medio de un procedimiento

lo intente de manera análoga a como se hace normalmente con un array

al compilar me dice que el paso de argumento 'rellenar' es de tipo puntero es incompatible

y que 'struct preguntas es **'

Este es el código

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct preguntas{

    char pregunta[40];
    char respuestas[40];
    char correcta[15];
};

void rellenar(struct preguntas *A[]);

int main (){
    struct preguntas quest[3];
    rellenar(&quest[3]);

    printf("%s",quest[0].pregunta);

    return 0;
}    

void rellenar(struct preguntas *A[3]){

    scanf("%s",A[0]->pregunta);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En C/C++ los arreglos y los apuntadores están muy relacionados, ten en cuenta que cuando declaras un arreglo `struct preguntas quest[3]` y lo pasas como parámetro de una función lo puedes recibir como un puntero a un tipo **struct preguntas** (`struct preguntas *A`).

Sabiendo esto al declarar esta instrucción `rellenar(&quest[3]);` lo que estas haciendo es hacer referencia a la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del arreglo, esperando recibir la dirección de memoria de un puntero `struct preguntas *A[3]`, siendo igual a `struct preguntas **A`, de allí el error.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct preguntas{
    char pregunta[40];
    char respuestas[40];
    char correcta[15];

} preguntas;

void rellenar(struct preguntas *A, size_t len);

int main (void){
    preguntas quest[3];
    rellenar(quest, 3);

    printf("%s", quest[0].pregunta);

    return 0;
}    

void rellenar(preguntas *A, size_t len){
    for (int k=0; k < len; k++) {
        printf("%d - pregunta:  ", (k + 1));
        scanf("%s", A[k].pregunta);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `rellenar(&quest[3])` pasa como parámetro la dirección del cuarto elemento de la matriz, no del primero.

Answer (score 0):

lo que pasa es que le estas pasando  a la función `void rellenar(struct preguntas *A[]);` un  `struct` de pregunta el cual solo debería de ser así  `(preguntas ,*A[])`
 y el  puntero al igual que  con las demás funciones a las cuales le estas pasando el puntero